# DNS objects in Maltego

Tags: dns, dns-domain

I don't understand what is a DNS object in Maltego. I know what is the NS and MX information related to a Domain. However, "to DNS Name [Robtex]" transform gives me many DNS Objects and I don't know how to read them.

Official documentation says that they are DNS name entries in DNS zone files. But, what does the "DNS Object" name means? Is the name of the zone file? What they represent?

Orange: dns name object (what I don't understand). Green: Mail servers. Red: NS Server

[image]

Comment: You may want to post an example screenshot. That will make this easier to understand.

Comment: @Daisetsu Yes, sorry! My fault. I uploaded a screenshot of my maltego project which shows the DNS objects (orange).

Comment: Looks like `A` records.